# Filter data based on User field cakePHP

Tags: cakephp

So I have a company based system and I am keeping all data within the one database and I separate the data by using a site_id field which is present in all tables and in the users table.

Now at the moment I am doing a condition on every single find('all'). Is there a more global way to do this. Maybe in the AppController? Even for saving data I am having to set the site_id every single save.

Something like

```
public function beforeFilter() {

    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->set('site_id', $this->Auth->user('site_id'));

}
```

Any direction would only help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR:**

Create a Behavior with a `beforeFind()` method that appends a `site_id` condition to all queries.

**Example/Details:**

Create a behavior something along the lines of the below.  Note, I'm getting the siteId from a Configure variable, but feel free to get that however you want.

```
<?php
class SiteSpecificBehavior extends ModelBehavior {

    public function setup(Model $Model, $settings = array()) {
        $Model->siteId = Configure::read('Site.current.id');
    }

    public function beforeFind(Model $Model, $query = array()) {
        $siteId = $Model->siteId;
        $query['conditions'][$Model->alias . '.site_id'] = $siteId ;
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Then on any/all models where you want to make sure it's site-specific, add:

```
public $actsAs = array('SiteSpecific');
```

This can be tweaked and improved up certainly, but it should give you a good idea.

Comment: Very clever! Thank you very much with your accurate code and help.